# Как сделать загрузку изображений с ограничениями?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать загрузку изображений с ограничениями? Т.е. нужны ограничения по размеру файлу и по изображению. Надо чтобы при нажатию загружалась картинка например с размером 200 * 200 и размер файла!

```css
#picture{
 border:1px solid; 
 background-color:#FFF;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.picture{
 width:460px;
 height:600px;
}

#imageFace{
 background:url("../images/faces/Face_3.jpg") no-repeat bottom;
 background-size:100%;
 z-index:-1;
}


.button{ 
width:60px;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid_6 prefix_3 suffix_3">
  <div id="picture" class="picture">
         <div id="imageFace" class="picture"></div>
        </div>
  </div>


    <p><button id="save" class="button" onload="imgLoaded(this)" onClick="javascript:savePicture();">Save Picture</button></p>
```

Comment: Проверка делается на сервере, а не на клиенте

Comment: На клиенте можно проверить лишь размер файла. тут пример http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html какой-никакой.

Comment: Ну значит размер файла, пытался гуглить, но не на гуглил(

Answer (score 3):

Средствами клиента, выполнить данную задачу, не представляется возможным, ввиду невозможности прямого доступа из браузера к файловой системе. Проверки подобного рода, всегда осуществляются на стороне сервера. Загружается файл в виде потока на сервер, если в процессе загрузки обнаруживается превышение допустимого размера файла, идет прекращение загрузки с возвратом кода ошибки. Если файл уложился в размер, он приводится к изображению (как, это уже зависит от типа бекэнда который вы используете), дальше проверяется размеры растра и если они не соответствуют требованиями, возвращается код ошибки.

Comment: А как сделать без проверки? Просто на нажатию на кнопку?
Нашел этот код, но как с имитировать input type file, но при клике на кнопку:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){
         $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");        
    });
});

Comment: Функция $().load загружает в контейнер файл находящийся в сети. В приведенном вами примере, она загружает в div demo_test.txt по относительному пути http://domain/demo_test.txt . Загрузить таким образом файл с локальной машины клиента нельзя.